# Disable "chrome is out of date" notification

Tags: google-chrome, kiosk

I have a touchscreen application optimised and running in a Chrome kiosk mode. It runs totally offline and due to some updates to Chrome breaking the application I've had to lock it to a fixed version of Chrome (v37.x). 
I've been able to prevent Chrome from auto-updating itself using the ADM/gpedit methods (http://www.wikihow.com/Completely-Disable-Google-Chrome-Update), but Chrome is now displaying a message on screen to say it is out of date.

[image: Chrom is out of date message]

Has anybody been able to find a way to disable this notification?

Comment: I am using portable version of chorme for touchscreen kiosk application. It has already disabled auto-update and don't display 'out of date' notification.
Check: http://www.chrome-portable.com/index.php/google-chrome-offline-installer

Comment: Thanks py3r3str - that site didn't have the version I needed but was able to get a version of Chromium from http://www.chrome64bit.com/index.php/chromium-64-bit-for-windows but then I had the issue with Chromium not having codecs for video playback. Still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 24):

Ubuntu + Chrome

param that worked for me `--simulate-outdated-no-au='Tue, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 GMT'`

Full launch command:
`google-chrome --start-fullscreen --incognito --simulate-outdated-no-au='Tue, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 GMT' "http://127.0.0.1/" &`

Comment: This works for me in CentOS as well. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me on Fedora. I pared it down to this and put it in my .bashrc like so for my current needs:
`alias chrome='google-chrome --simulate-outdated-no-au="Tue, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 GMT" "http://127.0.0.1/" &'`

Answer (score 8):

Changing the Chrome link to execute

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --simulate-outdated-no-au="01 Jan 2199"
```

worked like a charm for me. Thanks for the neat trick, really saved my day.

However, don't forget to also change the HTML association in the registry e. g. if Chrome is your default browser. This snippet will do the trick:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\" --simulate-outdated-no-au=\"01 Jan 2199\" --single-argument %1"
```

Answer (score 7):

We had same problem, but one of my colleagues got the answer (so far OK).

We are using Windows so batch file in startup for start chrome with incognito kiosk and update interval.

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application

start chrome.exe --incognito --window-position=0,0 --kiosk --check-for-update-interval=604800 "facebook.com"

exit    

--check-for-update-interval= 7days we are restarting the PC every day so update never tiger.
```

This command line switch is specified [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#check-for-update-interval).

Answer (score 5):

You may want to try editing sources: 
 https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/lkcr/chrome/browser/ui/views/outdated_upgrade_bubble_view.cc (or just read them to get the logic of the notification)

```
// static
void OutdatedUpgradeBubbleView::ShowBubble
```

Don't show notification bubble if there is already bubble shown:

```
// The currently showing bubble.
OutdatedUpgradeBubbleView* g_upgrade_bubble = nullptr;
...
  if (g_upgrade_bubble)
    return;
```

The widget is not available on some OS (desktop Chrome OS based on linux) and available on Windows, MacOSX and non-ChromeOS Linux:

```
bool OutdatedUpgradeBubbleView::IsAvailable() {
// This should only work on non-Chrome OS desktop platforms.
#if defined(OS_WIN) || defined(OS_MACOSX) || \
    (defined(OS_LINUX) && !defined(OS_CHROMEOS))
  return true;
#else
  return false;
#endif
```

They have maximum count for bubble ignores, but this is used only in telemetry (metrics), not to disable bubble:

```
// The maximum number of ignored bubble we track in the NumLaterPerReinstall
// histogram.
const int kMaxIgnored = 50;
```

And https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/lkcr/chrome/browser/ui/views/outdated_upgrade_bubble_view.h file

```
// OutdatedUpgradeBubbleView warns the user that an upgrade is long overdue.
// It is intended to be used as the content of a bubble anchored off of the
// Chrome toolbar. Don't create an OutdatedUpgradeBubbleView directly,
// instead use the static ShowBubble method.
```

Easiest edit is to set `g_upgrade_bubble` to non-zero value. Either with code editing or with runtime memory editing with debugger or possibly, [game trainer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trainer_(games)) like Cheat Engine or smth or with "chrome.dll" patching.

The bubble is started from `src/chrome/browser/ui/views/toolbar/toolbar_view.cc`  https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/ui/views/toolbar/toolbar_view.cc?q=OutdatedUpgradeBubbleView

```
  if (OutdatedUpgradeBubbleView::IsAvailable()) {
    registrar_.Add(this, chrome::NOTIFICATION_OUTDATED_INSTALL,
                   content::NotificationService::AllSources());
    registrar_.Add(this, chrome::NOTIFICATION_OUTDATED_INSTALL_NO_AU,
                   content::NotificationService::AllSources());

void ToolbarView::Observe(...
  switch (type) {
    case chrome::NOTIFICATION_OUTDATED_INSTALL:
      ShowOutdatedInstallNotification(true);
      break;
    case chrome::NOTIFICATION_OUTDATED_INSTALL_NO_AU:
      ShowOutdatedInstallNotification(false);
      break;

void ToolbarView::ShowOutdatedInstallNotification(bool auto_update_enabled) {
  if (OutdatedUpgradeBubbleView::IsAvailable()) {
    OutdatedUpgradeBubbleView::ShowBubble(app_menu_button_, browser_,
                                          auto_update_enabled);
  }
}
```

Triggered by src/chrome/browser/upgrade_detector.cc  with "`NOTIFICATION_OUTDATED_INSTALL`" https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/upgrade_detector.cc?q=NOTIFICATION_OUTDATED_INSTALL&sq=package:chromium&dr=C

```
void UpgradeDetector::NotifyUpgradeRecommended() {
  notify_upgrade_ = true;

  TriggerNotification(chrome::NOTIFICATION_UPGRADE_RECOMMENDED);
  if (upgrade_available_ == UPGRADE_NEEDED_OUTDATED_INSTALL) {
    TriggerNotification(chrome::NOTIFICATION_OUTDATED_INSTALL);
  } else if (upgrade_available_ == UPGRADE_NEEDED_OUTDATED_INSTALL_NO_AU) {
    TriggerNotification(chrome::NOTIFICATION_OUTDATED_INSTALL_NO_AU);
  } else if (upgrade_available_ == UPGRADE_AVAILABLE_CRITICAL ||
             critical_experiment_updates_available_) {
    TriggerCriticalUpdate();
  }
}
```

called from `void UpgradeDetectorImpl::NotifyOnUpgradeWithTimePassed` https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/upgrade_detector_impl.cc?rcl=0&l=455

```
    const base::TimeDelta multiplier = IsTesting() ?
        base::TimeDelta::FromSeconds(10) : base::TimeDelta::FromDays(1);

    // 14 days when not testing, otherwise 140 seconds.
    const base::TimeDelta severe_threshold = 14 * multiplier;
    const base::TimeDelta high_threshold = 7 * multiplier;
    const base::TimeDelta elevated_threshold = 4 * multiplier;
    const base::TimeDelta low_threshold = 2 * multiplier;

    // These if statements must be sorted (highest interval first).
    if (time_passed >= severe_threshold || is_critical_or_outdated) {
      set_upgrade_notification_stage(
          is_critical_or_outdated ? UPGRADE_ANNOYANCE_CRITICAL :
                                    UPGRADE_ANNOYANCE_SEVERE);

      // We can't get any higher, baby.
      upgrade_notification_timer_.Stop();
    } else if (time_passed >= high_threshold) {
      set_upgrade_notification_stage(UPGRADE_ANNOYANCE_HIGH);
    } else if (time_passed >= elevated_threshold) {
      set_upgrade_notification_stage(UPGRADE_ANNOYANCE_ELEVATED);
    } else if (time_passed >= low_threshold) {
      set_upgrade_notification_stage(UPGRADE_ANNOYANCE_LOW);
    } else {
      return;  // Not ready to recommend upgrade.
    }
  }

  NotifyUpgradeRecommended();
```

Comment: Was added in https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/2a54f2df467d56235e34668ceef8c8625c327e0f - 2013 Feb 13. " Add an outdated upgrade bubble view. Show a new bubble when the current install is more than on major revision away from what's available. BUG=151996", review https://chromiumcodereview.appspot.com/11440020. The bug "report" is not public: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=151996

Comment: bin patch: 0x5dc3558bec5151833dZZZZZZZZZZ755c68 -> 0x75 to 0x74 ?

Comment: Would you kindly explain how we can come up with a binary patch like the one you just mentioned? That one doesn't work for me. I'm familiar with assembly and all, but I have no idea what to search for (whether in the DLL or in cheat engine).

Comment: Mehrdad, I tried cheat engine too, but failed to disable counter. Idea of binary patch is to find some functions from upgrade_detector.cc / upgrade_detector_impl.cc / outdated_upgrade_bubble_view.cc files (using xref cross-reference tool in advanced disassemblers from string constants like "OutdatedUpgradeBubble.Show"), then find some counter/pointer variable and change [jnz to jz](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html#x74) in its test. Binary patch may fail for signature check.

Comment: Ahh, I was going to try searching for the constants but didn't think that's how you did it. Cool, thanks!

Comment: Update: I think I found a much nicer solution. Just add a DLL to `AppInit_DLLs` that dynamically patches `IsOS` to return with the `OS_DOMAINMEMBER` bit set (make sure to only do this for `chrome.exe`), then set the group policy as desired. Now Chrome thinks you're connected to a domain and stops nagging you.

Comment: Edit: Actually Chrome nagged me again, so that doesn't seem like it worked. :( Not sure what's going on...

Answer (score 2):

Bumped into this issue in a local kiosk project using Chromium 91. Ran with the flag --simulate-outdated-no-au which instructs the browser to simulate the browser being out of date AND have auto-update off. The notification is now consistently gone. Hope this helps anyone still running into this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me in plain Windows:

Created a batch file to launch Chrome as below. The annoying prompt that was tormenting me every 5 minutes - gone. Note the double-quotes instead of single ones.

```
cd C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application

start chrome --simulate-outdated-no-au="01 Jan 2032" "https://google.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu, if you start Chrome from the applications menu, you have to edit the applications manifest file:
`sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop`
and change respective execute lines to:
`Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --simulate-outdated-no-au='Tue, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 GMT' %U`
and
`Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --simulate-outdated-no-au='Tue, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 GMT'`
and
`Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --incognito --simulate-outdated-no-au='Tue, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 GMT'`

Answer (score 0):

[On the google forum some guy writes](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/ZewbdYlpT3E/MqzIBy9L7PoJ), that in order to disable automatic updates including the notification, you can set a specific GPO.

Comment: Thanks, tried but that doesn't totally disable it either.

Answer (score 0):

Step One:

1. Run: gpedit.msc
2. Navigate to: 
   Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates.
   Right-click Administrative Templates, and select Add/Remove Templates.
   Add the chrome.adm (will have to download this) template via the dialog.
3. Go to Classic Administrative Templates/Google/Google Update/Preferences
   “Enable” the Auto-update check period policy override state, and disable all auto-update checks.
4. Go to Google Update->Applications->Google Chrome
   “Enable” the Update policy override state, and set the policy to updates disabled
5. Go to Google Update->Applications->Google Chrome Binaries
   “Enable” the Update policy override state, and set the policy to updates disabled
6. Go to Google Update ->Applications->Update Policy Override Default
   “Enable” the Update policy override state, and set the policy to updates disabled

Step Two:
Go to Task Scheduler (via Administrative Tools) go to Task Scheduler Library and disable the two Chrome update entries.

Step Three:
On Chrome shortcut properties change the target to:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" /high-dpi-support=1 /force-device-scale-factor=1 --check-for-update-interval=604800

Comment: Using group policy editor is not an acceptable answer for computers not on a group policy as there is no gpedit.msc snapin.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers address the core question here, about modifying Chrome or running it a certain way, but I'll give an alternative...

We built an application used within the organisation that has similar characteristics - full screen, must work offline, some installations will be away from internet (can't get updates) etc. Two of chromes popups were annoying, namely "restore session?" and "chrome is out of date".

Those pop-ups make sense for a browser but our app is essentially not a browser any more.

Solution: build into an electron app. Kiosk mode and loads of other benefits (access to os, developers can show menu and dev tools etc). It also means you control when updates happen rather than Chrome auto updating, or trying to.

Electron worked great for us.